# Redirect after login and logout adds leading slash to URI, which causes exception

Tags: symfony, routes

I am using FOSUserbundle with the SonataUserbundle. I am not sure, which bundle this error belongs to, but I will try here first. Everytime I login and logout I get redirected:
After logging in, I get redirected to /app_dev.php///dashboard (3 leading slashes)
After logging out, I get redirected to /app_dev.php//login (2 leading slashes)

Here us my security.yml

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:             ^/.*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
                logout:             true
                anonymous:          true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: [ROLE_USER] }

    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
```

Can anybody hint me, what I might be missing?

> @stof Owner stof commented 39 minutes ago
>
> The redirection after login is handled by the SecurityBundle, not by
>   FOSUserBundle (we don't handle the login itself) @stof stof closed
>   this 39 minutes ago

Comment: Without any configuration, a logout will by default redirect to `/`. It might be a configuration error in your web server that causes this.

Comment: Seems like there might be a little bug. Also possible that it has to do with my web server config, but still there is some inconsistent behaviour in the generation of the requests base URL.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15016

Answer (score -1):

You have to change target path:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                default_target_path: you_target_path
```

[Read more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-success)